# Apostrophes in the same string in QUERY Google Sheets function

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

> =TRANSPOSE(QUERY(sorting!A57:A,"select * where A contains '"&$A57&"'"))

This is what I'm currently using to make a word tree based on my A column. I want to find all instances of A57 in the A column and fill the rest of the row with those. I have 2 issues that I can't seem to squash:

1. If I have an apostrophe it fails (circled in green in the screenshot)
2. I want whole word matches and not parts of words (circled in red) e.g. "is" should return "is he"  "is it"   "is it the"  and NOT "fish"  "wish" etc.

[Google Sheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxEkB.png)

Comment: i forgot to circle line 58 in green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

> =TRANSPOSE(QUERY(sorting!A1:A,"select * where A matches "".*\b"&$A1&"\b.*"""))

both problems 1 and 2 solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> =TRANSPOSE(QUERY(sorting!A1:A,"select * where A matches '.*\b"&$A1&"\b.*'"))

This solves problem 2. Still affected by problem 1.